# How/should one remove old websocket connections?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using 'ws' on Node.js and I'm not really sure how old connections are removed (old connections being disconnects or idle ones, this may be two different issues). Do I need to implement this manually for the two types?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to first maintain a list of live web socket connection objects in your server end. When the user disconnects from web socket  by closing the browser or any other means you need to delete the user web socket connection object from the list.

Server side codes. You can refer to members array in the following code for handling this.

```
io.on("connection",function(client)
{
  client.on("join",function(data)
  {
    members[membercount] = client;
    membername[membercount] = data;
    membercount++;
    for(var i =0 ;i <members.length;i++)
    {
      members[i].emit("message",membername);
    }
  });
  client.on("messages",function(data)
  {
    for(var i =0 ;i <members.length;i++)
    {
      if(members[i].id !== client.id)
      {
        members[i].emit("message",data);
      }
    }
  });
  client.on("disconnect",function(data)
  {
    for(var i =0;i<members.length;i++)
    {
      if(members[i].id ===  client.id )
      {
        membercount--;
        members.splice(i,1);
        membername.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
    for(var i =0 ;i <members.length;i++)
    {
      members[i].emit("message",membername);
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps !!!!!

Comment: What about if a client doesn't nicely disconnect? Does a heartbeat fail or something? Is the disconnect still triggered? Thanks!

Comment: Since it is web socket your node js framework will be listening for the open web socket connection. Whenever browser is closed it will notify your disconnect callback method. You have to manage the disconnect by deleting the closed instance. Hope this work for you !!!!!!!